# Compare 2 values in foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery

For each day, I do another foreach to return css `top` value:

```
$('.day').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.event').each(function() {
    var top = $(this).css('top');
  });
});
```

I would like to know if I can compare 2 `top` value?
I need that because, if 2 `top` value are equals, I add new class.

EDIT :

For example :

First event : 2017-08-07 at 8am

Second event : 2017-08-07 at 8am

Third event : 2017-08-07 at 2pm

In my website:

```
-8am is 'top: 50px'
-2 pm is 'top: 600px'

If first-event->top-position == second-event->top-position
```

I hope, this will help you.

Comment: Add in if statement, such as if (top === whatever) { //do some work}

Comment: Are there only ever two?

Comment: Which 2 do you want to compare?

Comment: @TGarrett : I cant compare with "whatever". If 2 events are on same time, i add class to have different style.
--- Darren Sweeney : Can be a lot of event at the same time per day.
--- JayMee : I would like to compare 2 top position because top position define 'time' (hour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can compare the top position of .day with the top position of its children, hoping this is what you meant.

Edited to compare top position of event compared to previous event for that day

```
var pos;
$('.day').each(function(__idx, __el) { 
  pos = false;    
  $(__el).find('.event').each(function(_idx, _el) {
       if(pos){
           if($(_el).position().top === pos){
               //do your thing here
           }
      }
      pos = $(_el).position().top;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not exactly what i want. I would like to compare 2 events. Top position define the start_time of the event. I would like to compare to add class for diffrent style.

Comment: Edited post to compare events within the same day

Comment: Yes it woks ! This added my class on the second element, how add same class to the first 'true' element ?

Comment: I answered my own question, I used .pev(). Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator or an if/else. I prefer ternary in such cases.
You can compare values by

```
var top = topValRec === topValOld? /*value if condition is true*/ : /*  value if condition is false */
```

Here `topValRec` is the recent value and `topValOld` is the value it needs to be compared with

So if I wanted top to have value 10 if condition is true and 20 if condition is false I'd write

```
var top = topValRec === topValOld ? 10 : 20
```

### Edit 17<sup>th</sup> August

```
var position;
$('.day').each(function() {
    position = false;
    $(this).find('.event').each(function() {
        var classToBeAdded = $(this).position().top === position ? "class_Name_If_True" : "class_Name_If_False";
        $(this).addClass(classToBeAdded);
  });
 position = $(_el).position().top;
});
```

Comment: thanks, I understand what you mean, but I dont understand how this can be works with my code. Can you explain with my example ?

Comment: Not on PC right now replied via mobile phone, will be on PC shortly, will update answer shortly probably an hour or so, meanwhile I'll try to write code on mobile.

Comment: @Eric answered my question, but I would be glad to know yours

Comment: @Reitrac I've updated the answer sorry for delay. I am not well so, took me fair time to get up and running. BTW I supposed that you wanted to add different classes based on  condition, if there is something else you wished to do I'll be glad to know.

Comment: thanks ! I'll try and keep u informed :) have another questions but based on WordPress :)

Comment: Sorry @Reitrac don't have experience of wordpress

Comment: No problem, i have another quesiton about jQuery, i create new thread ?

Comment: Yes as this question has been answered you have to create new thread, and comment the link I'll see what I can do @Reitrac